# Kubernetes(EKS) and AWS Lambda communicate with each other

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, kubernetes-nodeport

I have a EKS cluster which servers publicly available end points. However, i want to now add an end point which should only be accessible in the same VPC. How can i achieve something like this in EKS. For example, let a service A only be accessible from within the same VPC.

is this possible to natively achieve in EKS (Kubernetes) where I can place the Lambda in the same VPC as EKS cluster and then only allow communication between the two. I dont want the end point to be available publicly. I don't think i can use ClusterIP service as it only lets resources inside the cluster communicate. can I use a different service type to let service be accessible in only a VPC.

Any help here would be really great, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an AWSLBController, deploy an ingress with [internal](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/#scheme) load balancer annotations.

Then your lambda in the same VPC may reach this load balancer.

Additionally, I would choose to set up a [private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) in Route53 as opposed to setting up a DNS record with a load balancer's CNAME value.
Because load balancer DNS name is difficult to memorize,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am trying this now, but i dont understand why would i need a "private hosted zone" part, can't i just use the internal address of the load balancer AWS provides and make end point using it?

Comment: Private hosted zone broadcast dns values only in VPC. The values which you created in private zones will not be available from public (internet). 
The load balancer dns will be something like `k8s-NS_NAME-INGRESS_NAME-xxxxxx`, so this is not memorizable I suggested to create something memorizable dns with private zone. (All of this is optional)

Comment: I tried creating the Internal ALB and placed the lambda function in the same VPC as EKS Cluster but when i try to call an end point using ALB DNS Name, i get a 504 gateway timeout, not sure how to debug this, any ideas?